# How to loop through multiple websites using read_html in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm having trouble creating a loop to `read_html` and extract the information I needed. I was able to create a loop to extract from one website.

For example: Below is my code to extract title, description, and keywords from Amazon website.

```
URL <- read_html("http://www.amazon.com")
library(rvest)
results <- URL %>% html_nodes("head")

library(dplyr)
records <- vector("list", length = length(results))

for (i in seq_along(records)) {
  title <- xml_contents(results[i] %>% html_nodes("title"))[1] %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)
  description <- html_nodes(results[i], "meta[name=description]") %>% html_attr("content")
  keywords <- html_nodes(results[i], "meta[name=keywords]") %>% html_attr("content")
  records[[i]] <- data.frame(title = title, description = description, keywords = keywords)
}
```

But, what if I have:

```
name <- c("amazon", "apple", "usps")
url <- c("http://www.apple.com,
             "http://www.amazon.com",
             "http://www.usps.com")
    webpages <- data.frame(name, url)
```

How could I include `read_html` into the existing loop which I created to extract those information I want and also include the URL name.

**Desired Output Eexample**

```
url                      title            description               keywords
http://www.apple.com     Apple    Apple's website description     Apple, iPhone, iPad
http://www.amazon.com    Amazon   Amazon's website description    Shopping, Home, Online
http://www.usps.com      USPS     USPS's website description      Shipping, Postage, Stamps
```

Thank you for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this may work for you.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

webpages <- data.frame(name = c("amazon", "apple", "usps"),
                        url = c("http://www.amazon.com",
                                "http://www.apple.com",
                                "http://www.usps.com"))


webpages <- apply(webpages, 1, function(x){
  URL <- read_html(x['url'])

  results <- URL %>% html_nodes("head")

  records <- vector("list", length = length(results))

  for (i in seq_along(records)) {
    title <- xml_contents(results[i] %>% html_nodes("title"))[1] %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)
    desc <- html_nodes(results[i], "meta[name=description]") %>% html_attr("content")
    kw <- html_nodes(results[i], "meta[name=keywords]") %>% html_attr("content")
  }

  return(data.frame(name = x['name'],
                    url = x['url'],
                    title = ifelse(length(title) > 0, title, NA),
                    description = ifelse(length(desc) > 0, desc, NA),
                    kewords = ifelse(length(kw) > 0, kw, NA)))
})

webpages <- do.call(rbind, webpages)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's very comprehensive. One thing I noticed is that when the loop extracts information from Amazon by itself, it will do it, but when it does it with multiple websites, it will show Amazon as "Robot Check" on the title. I guess it's their API thing.

Comment: If you've tried accessing Amazon programmatically too many times in a row, it is likely that you are being redirected to a CAPTCHA page.