# How can I fix "connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds" while scraping in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I was trying to scrape multiple websites to extract website title, description, and keywords. It was okay to scrape about 15 websites, but R keeps returning a timed out error when I try to scrape more.

**Here is the copy of the error message:**

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
  Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds
```

I tried to use `options(timeout = 400000)` but it doesn't work.

In addition, I was thinking about download the page and `read_html` it into R, but this idea isn't feasible as I have a list of many URLs.

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this problem could be closing the browser after every iteration. You can try opening a new browser for every webpage and then close it after scraping. This can be done in a loop for all the websites that needs to be scraped.

Comment: great idea, however I'm not sure how to do that in the loop. Does it require additional package? Sounds like I need to use RSelenium.

Comment: Yes,you can do that using RSelenium. which has inbuilt functions that close the browser and open

https://ropensci.github.io/RSelenium/reference/rsDriver.html
`# NOT RUN {

# start a chrome browser

rD <- rsDriver()

remDr <- rD[["client"]]

remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com/ncr")
remDr$navigate("http://www.bbc.com")
remDr$close()
# stop the selenium server
rD[["server"]]$stop()

# if user forgets to stop server it will be garbage collected.
rD <- rsDriver()
rm(rD)
gc(rD) `

Comment: I saw that too when I did a search on RSelenium. Looks like I need to modify a lot of the codes because it involves read_html. Would you mind take a look at the solution posted by Matt to see if it's doable? Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54637802/how-to-loop-through-multiple-websites-using-read-html-in-r

Comment: Try this approach
`#website <- list(urls)

i<-1


dataset <- data.frame()

while(i <= 4){

  url <- website[i]

  remDr$navigate(url)

  

  #webElem_state <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "div.a-row.a-spacing-
small.review-data")

  

  page_source <- remDr$getPageSource()

  reviews <-read_html(page_source[[1]]) %>%     # read table 

    html_nodes(" class/xpath")%>% 

    html_text() #/or html_table()

  i <- i+1

  remDr$close()

  rm(pJS)

  }`